# rotating image again and again by 90 degrees in android

Tags: android, image, rotation

Can anyone tell me how to rotate an image again and again by 90 degrees in android? i made a button and i'm using that to rotate the image by 90 degrees. the code works fine for only one rotation, on the second rotation, the app crashes. Can anyone help me with that? assuming the i'm getting the image from the gallery of the camera and I have the bitmap in 'image' variable and 'imgPicture' is the image view. here is my code.

```
    public void Rotate(View view)
    {




    Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.postRotate(90);

        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width_temp1, height_temp1, m, true);
        imgPicture.setImageBitmap(image);

       // width_temp1 and height_temp1 are the width and height of the image that i'm getting
       // using the .getWidth() and .getHeight() functions of the bitmap.




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a bitmap for each rotation.The views have a property "RotationX", you can call setRotationX to implement rotation.

Comment: That's all well and good but here is the problem, some of the pictures that i load from the gallery are rotated and some come out fine, Usually the one's i have taken from the camera get rotated the wrong way. You can say that i can use the rotation once and be done with it but what if the user wants to rotate it again? what should i do then? because the app crashes the second time i click the button because of the reason you just told me.

Comment: actually never mind, i figured it out. I find the orientation using exif and then rotate the image if the orientation is 90. thanks for the help though :)